# Which register does store cmp result in arm?

Tags: assembly, arm, cpu-registers, calling-convention, status-register

I need to write a function that after work sets all registers except r0-r3 to their initial values. I use push and pop, but I can't find which register stores the value of CMP.

**UPD**. Thank you. It seems I am wrong. I had an assignment that had a hint: "Don't forget about callee-save registers", so it wasn't suggesting treating flags as callee saved)

Comment: That would be `CPSR`. But you don't access `CPSR` directly; instead you access it indirectly through e.g. conditional branch instructions.

Comment: functions generally dont care about the flags, interrupts yes, functions no.  Depending on the core it may already be doing that for you (for an interrupt)

Comment: Which ARM variant are you programming for?

Comment: Ask a new question if you have a question that needs a totally different answer than the original question.  I rolled back most of your edit that turned this a totally different question, about debugging your attempt at something.  If my answer answered this question, you can mark it "accepted" with the checkbox under the vote arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmp`, like all ARM instructions with an `s` suffix like `subs`, *s*et flags / condition codes.  These condition codes live in a register called `CPSR`, the [Current Program Status Register](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/cmsis/Core_A/html/group__CMSIS__CPSR.html).  Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#Registers

In all standard function-calling conventions, flags / condition codes are call-clobbered.  **You don't need to save/restore the caller's CPSR.**  Just let it be call-clobbered, along with r0..3.

But if you did, see https://heyrick.eu/armwiki/The_Status_register for examples like

```
    MRS     R0, CPSR                ; Copy CPSR into R0

    ...
    MSR     CPSR, R0                ; Copy R0 into CPSR
```